# How to force a custom component on every GameObject?

Tags: unity, component-based

I want to have a custom component which will have a drop down. I want this to be applied to ever GameObject in the project, which means every GameObject in the hierarchy and every GameObject prefab. Something like a transform component. It should not be removable, and it should be added by default when creating new GameObjects.

In the drop down, I will select a few options, and I want to store those values in an array on that custom forced component for that GameObject.

So if I have 2 new GameObjects in scene named XYZ and ABC, and the component is PQR, I should be able to do this-

```
ABC.GetComponent<PQR>().someArrayVar = whatever;
XYZ.GetComponent<PQR>().someArrayVar = anotherWhatever;
```

Anyone know how to do this? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think you can. You can make components be required for scripts (i.e. the script requires a RigidBody, for example) but I don't think you can make *every* gameobject automatically come with a custom component.

Comment: I think you'd have to create prefabs for each base GO type, then just use those to ensure they have the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because you are not allowed to [derive from the GameObject class](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22493/unity-3-sealed-class-gameobject-.html). The closest thing that I can think of would be to write an [extension method](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods) for gameObject that both attaches your custom component to the gameObject, as well as updating your array.

```
public static class Helper {

    public static void ModScriptArray(this GameObject gameObject, Data arrData)
    {
        PQR script = gameObject.GetComponent<PQR>();
        if (script == null)
            script = gameObject.AddComponent<PQR>();

        script.someArrayVar = arrData;
    }
}
```